# line and string position of grep match

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

I need to find a way to output the exact coordinates of a grep match from one file to another. So say 'patterns' contains a list of string patterns to match. 'Search' is a line-based text (ASCII) file containing the text to search in.

with:

```
grep -onf patterns search
```

I get the line and the pattern that matches in this line but not wherein the line the pattern matches and this is what I need. It's not restricted to using grep, awk etc. is also fine!

Can you guys help?

Comment: Also, use `grep --color` to highlight the match

Comment: this just colors the results and does not give me the position in the line ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{strings[$0]; next} {for (string in strings) if ( (idx = index($0,string)) > 0 ) print string, FNR, idx }' file1 file2
```

Since you're using `-f` with grep I assume it's strings you want to match on, not regexps.

The above just builds an array of strings from the contents of the first file and then for each line of the second file it looks for the index of where each string occurs on that lie and if it exists prints the string, the line number and the index (starting position) of where that string first appears on that line.

Comment: yep just strings. Wow thanks! it worked! Just because I'm really interested and if you have the spare time. Could you maybe explain what it is doing? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -v s="needle" 'i=index($0, s) {print NR, i}' file
```

This will print line # and line position of the searched item.

**UPDATE:**

```
while read -r line; do
    awk -v s="$line" 'i=index($0, s) {print s ":" NR "," i}' searches
done < patterns
```

OR pure awk based:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} {for (i in a) {if (p=index($0, i)) print i ":" NR "," p} }' patterns searches
```

Comment: this does not give me any result, how should it read two files? Can you maybe explain your answer?

Comment: Ok let me update the answer with 2 file examples also in few minutes.

Comment: thanks! works as well as the answer from Ed Morton! I really appreciate!

Comment: You're welcome. Reason why I also posted `while loop solution` because order of search string in output is not maintained in the awk solution. That part is well kept by `while read` solution.