# Using sed or awk (or similar) incrementally or with a loop to do deletions in data file based on lines and position numbers given in another text file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, replace

I am looking to do deletions in a data file at specific positions in specific lines, based on a list in a separate text file, and have been struggling to get my head around it.

I'm working in cygwin, and have a (generally large) data file (data_file) to do the deletions in, and a tab-delimited text file (coords_file) listing the relevant line numbers in column 2 and the matching position numbers for each of those lines in column 3.

Effectively, I think I'm trying to do something similar to the following incomplete sed command, where coords_file$2 represents the line number taken from the 2nd column of coords_file and coords_file$3 represents the position in that line to delete from.

```
sed -r 's coords_file$2/(.{coords_file$3}).*/\1/' datafile
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to include a loop or iteration so that sed runs first using the values in the first row of coords_file to fill in the relevant line and position coordinates, and then runs again using the values from the second row, etc. for all the rows in coords_file? Or if there's another approach, e.g. using awk to achieve the same result?

e.g. for awk, I identified these coordinates based on string matches using this really handy awk command from Ed Morton's response to this question: [line and string position of grep match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607324/line-and-string-position-of-grep-match).

```
awk 'NR==FNR{strings[$0]; next} {for (string in strings) if ( (idx = index($0,string)) > 0 ) print string, FNR, idx }' strings.txt data_file > coords_file.txt
```

Was thinking potentially something similar could work doing an in-place deletion rather than just finding the lines, such as incorporating a simple find and replace like `{if($0=="somehow_reference_coords_file_values_here"){$0=""}`. But it's a bit beyond me (am a coding novice, so I barely understand how that original command is actually working, let alone how to mod it).

File examples

data_file

```
@vandelay.1
blablablablablablablablablablablabla
+
mehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmeh
@vandelay.2
blablablablablablablablablablablabla
+
mehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmeh
@vandelay.3
blablablablablablablablablablablabla
+
mehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmeh
```

coords_file (tab-delimited)
(column 1 is just the string that was matched, column 2 is the line number it matched in, and column 3 is the position number of the match).

```
stringID 2 20
stringID 4 20
stringID 10 27
stringID 12 27
```

Desired result:

```
@vandelay.1
blablablablablablab
+
mehmehmehmehmehmehm
@vandelay.2
blablablablablablablablablablablabla
+
mehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmeh
@vandelay.3
blablablablablablablablabl
+
mehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehme
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated thanks! (And as I mentioned, I'm *very* new to this coding scene, so apologies if some of that doesn't make sense or my question format's shonky (or if the question itself is rudimentary)).

Cheers.

(Incidentally, this has all been a massive work around to delete strings identified in the `blablabla` lines of data_file *as well as* the same positions 2 lines below (i.e. the `mehmehmeh` lines), since the `mehmehmeh` characters are quality scores that match the `blablabla` characters for each sample (each `@vandelay.xx`). i.e. Essentially this: `sed -i 's/string.*//' datafile`, but also running the same deletion 2 lines below every time it identifies the string. So if there's actually an easier script to do just that instead of all the stuff in the question above, please let me know!)

Comment: The answer below looks like a fix for your described problem, .... but  if this is more than a one-off fix, I really hope you'll backtrack and fix your producing processes. It will only get worse if you leave this in place (from personal experience/observation ;-/ ) . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response @shelter. Yup, CWLiu's response was perfect. I'm hoping this is indeed a bit of a one-off! But will figure out how to backtrack and fix it earlier if it's an ongoing thing ;) . Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use one liner `awk` to do that,

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3;next} (FNR in a){$0=substr($0,0,a[FNR]-1)}1' coords_file data_file
@vandelay.1
blablablablablablab
+
mehmehmehmehmehmehm
@vandelay.2
blablablablablablablablablablablabla
+
mehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehmeh
@vandelay.3
blablablablablablablablabl
+
mehmehmehmehmehmehmehmehme
```

Brief explanation,

- `NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3;next}`: create the line number and the matching position map in array `a`. This part of expression would only process `coords_file` because of `NR==FNR`
- `(FNR in a)`: then `awk` would start to process `data_file`. Use the expression to search any FNR contained in array a.
- `$0=substr($0,0,a[FNR]-1)`: re-assign the `$0` to the line be cut.
- `1`: print all lines

Comment: Legend. This is perfect thanks. I don't have the rep to up vote sorry, but this is spot on.

Comment: And thanks for the detailed explanation as well btw. I have no coding background, so this kind of explanation definitely helps me begin to understand what's actually going on within commands. Cheers.